# Is there a way to set the environment path programmatically in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, path, environment-variables

Is there a way to set the global windows path environment variable programmatically (C++)?
As far as I can see, putenv sets it only for the current application.
Changing directly in the registry `(HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment)` is also an option though I would prefer API methods if there are?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

MSDN [Says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653(VS.85).aspx):

> Calling SetEnvironmentVariable has no
>   effect on the system environment
>   variables. **To programmatically add or
>   modify system environment variables,
>   add them to the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Environment registry key, then
>   broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message
>   with lParam set to the string
>   "Environment".** This allows
>   applications, such as the shell, to
>   pick up your updates. Note that the
>   values of the environment variables
>   listed in this key are limited to 1024
>   characters.

Comment: It should be noted that "Environment" string is in UTF16 form, so you should use `L` prefix. Sample code: `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)L"Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, NULL);`

Answer (score 12):

As was pointed out earlier, to change the PATH at the *machine level* just change this registry entry:

```
HLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

But you can also set the PATH at the *user level* by changing this registry entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\Path
```

And you can also set the PATH at the *application level* by adding the application\Path details to this registry entry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no API - changing the registry is the way to do it. The changed value will be used for processes starting after the change was made.

Also:  Notice that running applications must actively process the settings changed message and many (most?) do not do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it through the registry, you might want to look at the source code of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/SetEnv.aspx) program.

Microsoft also provides a small command line utility called setx with its [resource toolkits](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&displaylang=en), which will let you do this. By the way, the regular set command just lets you define local environment variables I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You are correct.
You also need to effect these settings without logging off

Send Message of borad casting to all windows SETTINGCHANGE for the parameter (LPARAM) "Environment" with SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG for some milliseconds(5000) using SendMessageTimeout API.

This is what setX.exe provided with resource Kit does.