# Commands Visibility at Command Prompty Not Using System32

Tags: windows

Let's say I have a foo.exe file that I want to use it from windows command prompt. I will go to the folder which contains foo.exe and run it. Now, if I want global access for foo.exe from anywhere in the command prompt I will put foo.exe in System32 folder.

This process makes System32 a dump ground. I was wondering if there are any other ways of globally accessing the .exe or bat files without having to dump all of them in System32 folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your PATH environment variable.  i.e. "set path=%path%;[newdir]"

where [newdir] is the new directory you want searched when you run commands.

[The PATH Environment Variable](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm)

Comment: You can also change the path on a windows machine by going to SystemProperties->Advanced->EnviromentVariables. At the top you have the user specific enviroment variables and at the bottom, the system wide ones. PATH can be in both.

Comment: Note that the path size is limited (length depends on OS). If you have a few installed software that have added their folders to the path, it might overflow. The way to avoid that is to create a separate system variable, say FOOS_DIR, and assign foo's dir to it. Then, add %FOOS_DIR% to the system path instead of the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this programatically ([StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531998/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-environment-path-programatically-in-c-on-windows)) or follow these instructions 
[How to set the path in Windows 2000 / Windows XP](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), [another one](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm).