# Can anyone give me a example of modifying windows environment system variables in WIX?

Tags: path, wix, environment

I still don't know how to add the installdir into the PATH of the Windows System Variables after I went through the WIX tutorial.

I tried to use

```
  Environment Id='UpdatePath' Action='create' Name='PATH'  System='yes' Value='[INSTALLDIR]'
```

But there was no change in the Path after I installed the program. I can hardly find sample code of WIX anywhere.
Please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
<Environment Id="PATH" Name="PATH" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Permanent="yes" Part="last" Action="set" System="yes" />
```

This should add a new entry to the environment path, set to `[INSTALLDIR].`

Comment: Setting `Permanent="no"` will remove the appended part (but not the entire value) on uninstall.

Comment: note INSTALLDIR is not a magic word - it needs to match the id of a directory which can be whatever you like (doesnt even need the caps, although they do have a special meaning in wix!)

Comment: This isn't working for me.  When I echo my %PATH% variable it is unchanged. Can anyone post a bit more of the context?  I've got it in a DirectoryRef per @Deqing's answer below, but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: [Wix Official Documentation Basic](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/environmentally-friendly/) and [Wix Official Documentation Detailed](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html) for `Environment` tag.

Comment: @KevinSmyth: If we set `Permanent="no"` what happens if more values from other installs are appended to the path environment variable by the time the user hits uninstall? Is the correct value still removed from the path environment variable?

Comment: With `Permanent="no"`, I tried uninstalling after adding more values to a environment variable manually. The correct value was removed after the uninstall leaving the other values untouched. Works great.

Comment: Update: After a few changes to the `wxs` file, the removal of the install directory from the environment variable stopped working. I am not sure if this is because the installer produced is buggy or I made some mistake.

Answer (score 24):

Another thing to note is, `Environment` need to be placed inside a component with directory, e.g.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="Path" Guid="{xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx}">
    <Environment Id="PATH" Name="PATH" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Permanent="no" Part="last" Action="set" System="no" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Details of Wix Element described at [Environment Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_environment.htm)

Comment: actually just needs to be in a fragment then component, no need for a directoryref

Comment: I'm trying to set env variable using this answer but without success: I can't find right place for `DirectoryRef`. I also tried to place `Component` without `DirectoryRef` parent. Could somebody suggest where should I place `Environment` tag in my wxs file: https://gist.github.com/pyeremenko/891eceb779197e4be240

Comment: I ended up putting `Component` (without `DirectoryRef`) right under the root level `Directory`, i.e., `<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">` and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same exact problem, this have worked for me:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DataBaseds_Service_Installer" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<ComponentGroup Id="Components" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
 
  ...some components  
</ComponentGroup>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="MYSQL_PASSWORD" Guid="..."
    <Environment Id=HERE YOU CAN ADD THIS  :)/>
  </Component>      
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" >
  <Component Id="Path" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="1014136b-a934-47db-bf69-5da949b2528b">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <Environment Id="PATH" Name="PATH" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Permanent="no" Part="last" Action="set" System="no" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```