# How can I make a c# command line application runnable in cmd.exe with installer?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, cmd, installation

I've written a C# command line application in visual studio. I would like to be able to run it as a command from the cmd.exe prompt application, after it installs. To do this I need to install the application in such a way that this would work

```
C:\Users\user3765372\Documents\>myAppName argument
```

a good example of an application with this functionality ins node.js eg:

```
C:\Users\user3765372\Documents\>nodejs server.js
```

Will cause node to run the server.js file. How can I make my program run like this for its commands?

Note my app isn't in Documents... its somewhere else.

I'm using [this plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) to create the installer

Update:

This should work.... I think I may be making a mistake:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "with an installer"?  Any simple Console Application can be ran from the command line and passed parameters.  You have access to these via `string[] args` in your `Main()` method.

Comment: @Tom I don't want to have to navigate to the location?

Comment: You add the folder containing your application to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @mikez how would I do that with an installer/in the program for a non-technical user trying to use my program?

Comment: @user3765372 What installer framework are you using? This is a common thing to do, so it should be easy.

Comment: @mikez anything in vs would do, I was trying to use the publish menu, but I'm pretty sure that is wrong...

Comment: @user3765372 In wix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1931644/517852

Comment: @mikez looking into it

Comment: So you just want to update the Environmental Variable %Path% with your programs directory?

Comment: @bill, no... not quite

Comment: Based on your update, that's exactly what you're trying to do in that registry key. Editing the key directly will require a reboot or at least a restart of all running applications to take in effect. The method I posted below will not require that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourAppPath = //whateverdirectoryyouwant;
string path = string.Format("{0};{1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine),yourAppPath);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Some users report using SetEnvironmentalVariable not taking effect. You can do this instead:

```
Process.Start("setx", string.Format("/M Path {0}",path));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an installation (msi file) recommend using the Wix installer for creating an installation, and using the environment tag. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931586/can-anyone-give-me-a-example-of-modifying-windows-environment-system-variables-i).

Alternately, you can use the Visual Studio Installer project but it will require a custom action.