# Adding environment variable in WiX bootstrapper

Tags: windows, wix

I have Wix bootstrapper that installs few MSI packages.
Is there any way I can add to path install folder one of these packages INSIDE this bootstrapper?
Something like this:

```
 <Environment Id="PATH" Name="PATH" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Permanent="yes" Part="last" Action="set" System="no" />
```

Or I have to add it inside one of these packages as component?

Comment: The second question is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356885/2226988).

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrapper projects are not supposed to change the state of the system (outside of the individual packages).

You would need to add it to one of the MSI projects.

This code block works for me.  Note `CreateFolder` is necessary to ensure the block is executed.

```
<Component Id="pathComponent" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes">
   <CreateFolder />
   <Environment Id="PATH" Name="PATH" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Permanent="no" Part="last" Action="set" System="yes" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Hmm, I have following problem:
I am installing MSI package, that I cannot modify. In that package you chose installation dir, and I need that dir to be in the path.

Comment: You could produce your own MSI that adds it to the Path.  You should be able to use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<Product ID>\InstallLocation` to find where it was installed.