# Set Environment variable on client machine using WiX toolset MSI installer

Tags: wix

I have to set Environment variable where this installer will be installed, but I am unable to do that.

I have tried the suggestions found in the following links without luck:

- [Can anyone give me a example of modifying windows environment system variables in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931586/can-anyone-give-me-a-example-of-modifying-windows-environment-system-variables-i)
- https://github.com/vibhorpg/wixsample/blob/main/Product_intel.wxs

So how can I set following environment on client system using WiX

```
<Environment Id="A_EXCELADDIN_LOG_PATH1" Name="A_EXCELADDIN_LOG_PATH" Value="%APPDATA%\A\logs" Permanent="no" Part="all" Action="set" System="no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's generally how you do it.  Only things that come to mind is first realize your specifying user profile so it'll only be for the person who installed the app  and second Windows Installer doesn't update the environment variable if a reboot is pending.  (Even if the pending reboot isn't from your MSI.)

Comment: can you paste a sample so that I can know where to exactly put the enviorment variable