# Keep Dll in custom folder

Tags: c++, windows

I have a C++ program with a depedency on external Dll [lets say dependent.dll], now If I keep..

- dependent.dll in executable folder, it works fine,  but if I keep
- dependent.dll in somne custom Folder,  it doesn't.

I have tried

```
LPCTSTR deplibFullPath = "C:\Program Files\My_Program\Dlls\dependent.dll";
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryEx(deplibFullPath , NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
```

It returns not null but whenever I access any function in dependent.dll, it doesnt works fine (crashes)

Any idea where I am doing wrong or what extra for i need to do.

Thanks

-Pankaj

Answer (score 3):

Your path is wrong. It should be

```
LPCTSTR deplibFullPath = "C:\\Program Files\\My_Program\\Dlls\\dependent.dll";
```

since \ is used to escape special commands in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your dll requires other dll's (dependencies) from that same folder. Try calling [AddDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before loading that one.

And I assume the single "\"s in your path is just a copy and paste error...

Comment: Note: That is a Windows 8 function.

Comment: Thanks Johnny but I am currently working on Windows 7 and AddDllDirectory is available minimum on Windows 8 :(

and yes, single "\s" were just typing error.

Comment: Ok. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919125/programmatically-adding-a-directory-to-windows-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, the problem was not in my LoadLibraryEx function but I was not using the GetProcAddress correctly. :(