# How to update PATH Variable permanently Using PHP

Tags: php, registry, environment-variables

Hi there I want to update `Path` environmental variable permanently through PHP script. I know about `putenv()` but it is not permanent. I have read some where of generating a `.reg` file with following content.

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
                    'PATH'='c:/abc/test/ImageMagick-6.7.8-Q8/convert.exe'
```

I have generated the file with content.

When I run this file, it shows me that file has been run successfully and key values containing in file is added in registry successfully. But When I go to path variable to check, my values are not there :-( 
Can any body tell me why is this happening. I am using `window 7`. But my work has also to be compatible with window xp. Or is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Need suggestions....

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have solved this issue. I have solved it by creating `.bat` file. The content of `.bat` file looks like

```
 @echo off
 set KeyName=Path
 set KeyValue="D:\songs;%PATH%"
 setx -m %KeyName% %KeyValue%
```

`-m` is used if you want to set it at `system level for all users`. If you want it to set only for current user, then remove `-m`.  The above command will set `D:\songs` in environement `Path` variable. To run this you need to be the administrator of the system.

Cheers if this is useful for any one :-)

Comment: setx is a Windows Resource Kit utility. Thanks for publishing this.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH environment variable in the registry is copied to a process' environment when the process is created.

cmd.exe (the command window or shell) is a process in it's own right. You have to `SET PATH=` within the shell to change it.

If you open a new command window, you should have the new PATH set. See also [Programmatically adding a directory to Windows PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919125/programmatically-adding-a-directory-to-windows-path-environment-variable?rq=1)