# PHP in Windows: add an environment variable for User or Machine

Tags: php, windows, path, environment-variables

I am trying to update the Path environment variable in Windows with a PHP script, but if I use `putenv()` it doesn't change. I can get the paths list in the Path variable but I am not able to update it.
Another problem is that if I use `getenv('Path')` to get the paths list, I have a unique string with all paths merged from the Path variable of User and of the Machine.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that, maybe acting directly in the registry key to update User Path variable.

---

UPDATE

I think I found out a half-solution, but it doesn't work as expected.

What do I want to do?
I just want to make a script that allow me to switch from a PHP version to another changing the Path variable.

I made the script, it seems to work and the Path variable is successfully updated, but even if I close and reopen the cmd prompt if I type `php -v` it doesn't seems to get the updated var. If I open the Environment Variables windows, then open the "Path" variable and click on Ok and Ok again, then the refresh is got but the cmd prompt.

This is very strange to me, and if I have to do this everytime, then script loose its benefit...

I recorded a video, I hope it explain the problem better than my English...
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ao2s4w8xSxBSh7RY4y5pB8u1g_QFSQ

This is the code of the script:

```php
// Load PHP available versions
$laragon_php_paths = 'D:\www-servers\laragon\bin\php';
$php_paths         = scandir($laragon_php_paths);
$path_var_name     = "Path";

// Backup before doing a disaster
$date = new DateTime();
exec('REG EXPORT HKCU\Environment BackupUserEnvironment_' . $date->format('YmdHisv') . '.reg');

// Load registry key of user's Path environment variable
exec('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment /v ' . $path_var_name, $output, $result);
$path       = explode('    ', $output[2]);
$path_array = explode(';', $path[count($path) - 1]);

// Get the current PHP Version and get the key of the item of the PHP bin path
foreach ($path_array as $key => $path_item) {
    if (strpos($path_item, $laragon_php_paths) !== false) {
        $the_key             = $key;
        $current_php_version = substr($path_item, strrpos($path_item, '\\') + 1);
    }
}

echo 'Available PHP versions:' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$i = 0;
foreach ($php_paths as $dir) {
    if ($dir === '.' || $dir === '..') continue;
    echo '    [' . ++$i . '] ' . $dir;
    if ($dir === $current_php_version) {
        echo ' [Current version]';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

// Get file descriptor for stdin
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Select a PHP version: ';
$fd     = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$choice = (int) fgets($fd);
echo PHP_EOL;

// Check if choice is between 1 and number of choices
if ($choice > 0 && $choice <= $i) {

    // Change the original php version with the new one
    $new_php_version      = $php_paths[$choice + 1];
    $path_array[$the_key] = $laragon_php_paths . '\\' . $new_php_version;
    echo 'PHP version changed to: ' . $new_php_version . PHP_EOL;

} else {
    echo 'No allowed choice, nothing changed.';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

// Escape some chars for cmd
$new_path_var = str_replace(['%', ' '], ['^%', '" "'], implode(';', $path_array));
$cmd          = 'REG ADD HKCU\Environment /f /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v ' . $path_var_name . ' /d ' . $new_path_var;

// Execute
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: _"but if I use putenv() it doesn't change"_ - of course it doesn't; the manual clearly states, _"The environment variable will only exist for the duration of the current request. At the end of the request the environment is restored to its original state."_ It is not the purpose of this function to manipulate your actual system PATH variable to begin with.

Comment: PHP directly messing with the registry does not sound like a good idea (and I wouldn't know how exactly to achieve that to begin with) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478816/1427878 has a suggestion using a `.bat` file, maybe that works for you. (Perhaps _triggered_ by PHP via `exec` or something, if necessary.)