# Adding to PATH via Python in Windows

Tags: python, path

I want to add GeckoDriver exe to `PATH` environment variable via a python script, I found an answer on StackOverflow but this didn't work for me. My code says the path was added, but when I check in `cmd` or through the system settings, it isn't there:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()+"\\driver\\"

if 'geckodriver' not in os.environ:
    print("Added")
    os.environ["Path"] = cwd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `setx` command to set permanent environmental variable under Windows. To run `setx` from Python, try this code:

```
from subprocess import check_output

cwd = os.getcwd()+"\\driver\\"

if 'geckodriver' not in os.environ:
    print("Added")
    check_output(f'setx Path "{cwd}"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The presented code will update the environment variable for the current shell and its children. It won't propagate up to setting the system-level settings.

The worse news, is that this can't be done easily. You either have to [edit the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/531998/4822566), or you may be able to use [`setx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/4822566) command line tool. Neither are particularly friendly from Python, and both have downsides.